# Help in recognizing a component

Tags: transistors, identification

[image][image]

Dear friends
i have a problem recognizing this component whether it is dual diodes or tranasistor and to find it's datasheet, can I find any help.
It is found in an LED lamp with PIR
thanks

Comment: Since the designator is U instead of Q or D it is likely not a transistor or diode.

Comment: there are Zener diodes, LDO regulators, and N-Channel MOSFET + Schottky barrier diode with a U designator but none are SOT-23.. https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/u4

Comment: I meant the component designator is U2. U generally means IC of some sort. I did not mean the code printed on component which incidentally starts with U too.

Comment: Ya I understand you are right thanks

Comment: is the marking LU? there seems to be a blob something obscuring the left end

Comment: No it is a logo, I added a bigger photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer is [Microne](http://www.microne.com.cn/en/) and the closest part I could find is [ME6208A30M3G](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809141122_MICRONE-Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6208A30M3G_C236694.pdf) which is a 3V LDO. As far as I can tell, Microne doesn't explain their markings anywhere, so it's impossible to say for sure, but the first two marking characters match. Maybe the other two characters are a traceability code.

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Linear-Voltage-Regulators-LDO_MICRONE-Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6208A30M3G_C236694.html))

Addendum:

I looked at a more popular Microne part in the same package (ME2188A50XG) and it looks like the first two characters of the marking are indeed the relevant part because they stay the same on all pictures while the last two change:

[image]

(Source: google images [search string: `ME2188A50XG`])

Comment: Yes you’re absolutely correct thanks a million